# Getting average of survey results when I only have the count for each response?

Tags: statistics, average

So I have the results from a survey, but they're aggregated by year and response number. I for the devil of me cannot figure out how to get average survey response by the scale. Like for instance, for 2010, I have:

\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}\hline\text{Value}&0 &  1 &  2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\\hline
\text{Frequency}&1 & 0 & 4 & 21 & 37 & 17\\\hline\end{array}

And the average of the bottom row is $13.33$, but that doesn't tell me what I want. That tells me the average number of responses, but I want the average response on the scale. I have no idea aside from making a dataset with 17 5s etc and then doing an average on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a basic example first: \begin{array}{|c|ccc|}\hline\text{Value}&1&2&3\\
\hline
\text{Frequency}&2&3&5\\\hline\end{array}

This is equal to the following dataset: $1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3$

We would calculate the average value by computing

\begin{align}\frac{\text{sum of items}}{\text{number of items}}&=\frac{1+1+2+2+2+3+3+3+3+3}{10}\\
&=\frac{23}{10}\\
&= 2.3\end{align}

This is equal to $$\frac{1\times 2+2\times 3+3\times 5}{2+3+5}=\frac{2+6+15}{10}=\frac{23}{10}=2.3$$

i.e we multiply each value by its frequency, add them together, and then divide by the sum of the frequencies

---

Therefore, we would compute \begin{align}\frac{0\times 1+1\times0+2\times 4+3\times 21+4\times 37+5\times 17}{1+0+4+21+37+17} &= \frac{0+0+8+63+148+85}{80}\\
&= \frac{304}{80}\\
&=3.8\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! This logic also helped me properly calculate the standard deviation for my frequencies.

Comment: No worries, this was how my Maths teacher back at school taught me to think about it and I think it really helps

Answer (score 0):

Multiply values with frequency (%) and sum.

Answer (score 0):

The survey received a total of $1 + 4 + 21 + 37 + 17 = 80$ responses, of which $1$ response was $0,$
$4$ responses were $2,$ and so forth.

If you had a list of all the responses, you would add up the $80$ numbers in the list and divide by $80$ to get the mean.
But in fact you *do* have a list of the responses, just not in the same order in which they were recorded. And since addition is commutative, the order does not matter.
The responses were
$$
0, 2, 2, 2, 2, \overbrace{3, \ldots, 3}^{\text{$21$ responses}},
\overbrace{4, \ldots, 4}^{\text{$37$ responses}},
\overbrace{5, \ldots, 5}^{\text{$17$ responses}}.
$$

The easiest way to add them up is by using multiplication to add up the repeated values:
$$
S = 0 + 4\times 2 + 21\times 3 + 37\times 4 + 17\times 5,
$$
and then $\frac{S}{80}$ is the mean value.